# Changing margins at runtime

Tags: android, view, runtime, margins

I'm trying to change the position of some TextViews in a FrameLayout by changing their margins at runtime using

```
MarginLayoutParams newMarginParams = new MarginLayoutParams(view.getLayoutParams());
newMarginParams.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams newLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        newMarginParams);
view.setLayoutParams(newLayoutParams);
```

I checked that the x and y values are correct, but the TextViews are not shown. I tried to call invalidate() for every TextView but it does not change anything...

The complete code is show below. The margin of every TextViews are updated in updateLayouts(...).

Anybody can help?

```
public class ARActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener, SensorEventListener{

    FrameLayout mainLayout;
    private CBCameraView cv;

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private Location mDeviceLocation;
    private float mDeviceAzimuth = 0;
    private double mDeviceInclination = 0;

    private static final float K = 0.1f; // filtering coefficient
    private static final float ONE_MINUS_K = 1 - K; // filtering coefficient

    private float xAngleWidth = 52.2f; // Samsung Galaxy S: 52.2
    private float yAngleWidth = 39.4f; // Samsung Galaxy S: 39.4

    private final float screenWidth = GlobalVars.screenWidth;
    private final float screenHeight = GlobalVars.screenHeight;

    private final float[] mR = new float[9];

    private final float[] I = new float[9];

    private final float[] orientation = new float[3];

    private final float[] remappedR = new float[9];

    private float[] mags;
    private float[] accels;

    int nARItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.ar_layout);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 1, this); 

        mDeviceLocation = GlobalVars.location;

        mainLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.ar_layout); 

        cv = new CBCameraView(this);
        cv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        mainLayout.addView(cv); 


        // Add ARViews

        Location location = new Location("me");
        location.setLatitude(41.371974);
        location.setLongitude(2.166978);

        ARView fs = new ARView(this);
        fs.azimuth = 0;
        fs.inclination = 0;
        fs.location = location;
        fs.setText("Bar seco");       

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        fs.setLayoutParams(params);

        mainLayout.addView(fs);
        nARItems = mainLayout.getChildCount();
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {        
        mDeviceLocation = location;
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){}

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){}

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1){}

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            mags = event.values.clone();
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            accels = event.values.clone();
            break;
        }
        if (mags != null && accels != null) {
            SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(mR, I, accels, mags);
            SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(mR, SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z, remappedR);
            SensorManager.getOrientation(remappedR, orientation);
            float tmp = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientation[0]);
            if(tmp<0)
                tmp += 360;

            if(Math.abs(mDeviceAzimuth - tmp)<300)
                mDeviceAzimuth = (float) (tmp * K) + (mDeviceAzimuth * ONE_MINUS_K);
            else
                mDeviceAzimuth = tmp;

            tmp = (float) Math.round(Math.toDegrees(orientation[1]));
            mDeviceInclination = (float)(-tmp * K) + (mDeviceInclination * ONE_MINUS_K);

            updateLayouts(mDeviceAzimuth, (float)mDeviceInclination, mDeviceLocation);
        }
    }

    public void updateLayouts(float azimuth, float zAngle, Location location)
    {       
        float leftArm = azimuth -(xAngleWidth/2);
        float rightArm = azimuth +(xAngleWidth/2);
        if(leftArm < 0)
            leftArm = leftArm + 360;
        if(rightArm > 360)
            rightArm = rightArm - 360;

        float upperArm = zAngle + (yAngleWidth/2);
        float lowerArm = zAngle - (yAngleWidth/2);

        for(int i=1; i<nARItems; i++)
        {

            ARView view = (ARView)mainLayout.getChildAt(i);
            if(location != null && view.location != null)
            {
                view.azimuth = location.bearingTo(view.location);

                if(view.azimuth < 0)
                    view.azimuth = 360+view.azimuth;
            }

            int x = (int)calcXvalue(leftArm, rightArm, view.azimuth);
            int y = (int)calcYvalue(lowerArm, upperArm, view.inclination);

            MarginLayoutParams newMarginParams = new MarginLayoutParams(view.getLayoutParams());
            newMarginParams.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams newLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    newMarginParams);
            view.setLayoutParams(newLayoutParams);
        }

    }

    public class ARView extends TextView
    {    
        public float azimuth;
        public float distance;
        public float inclination;
        public Location location;

        public ARView(Context context)
        {        
            super(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i know this comment is not related to the question asked. But i am trying to figure out what is xAngleWidth and yAngleWidth in the above code, is it the horizontalViewAngle and verticalViewAngle of Camera??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be with the layout being a framelayout. I have used MarginLayoutParams in my code before and it worked even though the part where I changed the margins looks the same as yours. The only difference was that I was using LinearLayout.